# org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: com.mycompany.model.NodeElement

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have base mapping class which contains some common fields

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
public class NodeElement {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private ElementPosition elementPosition;
}
```

And i have few classes which extends from this `NodeElement` class

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "node")
@Table(name = "NODE")
public class Node extends NodeElement {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_NODE_ID")
    private Node parentNode;

    @Column(name = "MESSAGE")
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "node", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<NodeButton> nodeButtons;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "node", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<NodeAsset> nodeAssets;
}
```

For CRUD operations i'm using spring-data repository:

```
public interface NodeElementRepository extends CrudRepository<NodeElement, String> {
}
```

And it's working perfectly fine for saving entities:

```
NodeElement nodeModel = elementConverter.convert(nodeElement);
this.nodeElementRepository.save(nodeModel);
```

But when i try to find entity by Id

```
Optional<NodeElement> node = this.nodeElementRepository.findById(nodeModel.getId());
```

i get following error:

```
 org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: by.com.lifetech.lifeEmployeeBot.model.NodeElement
```

Is it possible to get entity by using base repository? Or do i have to use specific one(`NodeRepository` instead of `NodeElementRepository`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed mapping of my `NodeElement` class:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Entity
@Data
public class NodeElement {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private ElementPosition elementPosition;
}
```

And after that i'm able to get entity by id by using `NodeElementRepository` class

Answer (score 0):

Try to change String for Long in

> public interface NodeElementRepository extends CrudRepository

If that doesnt work try to write Repository that extending JpaRepository

```
@Repository //remember about this!
public interface NodeElementRepository extends JpaRepository<NodeElement, Long> {
}
```

Also try method

```
.findOne(id)
```

Comment: I can't change `String` to `Long` because @Id of `NodeElement` has `String` type. I tried to change `CrudRepository` to `JpaRepository` but i anyway get the same error.

Comment: Think about changing it from String to Long and add adnotation above id "@GeneratedValue"